# Layout design for tablet

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I'm trying to design the layout for tablet. I want each control to have equal spaces between each other. How all of these can be aligned properly ? Sorry I cannot attach the image as I don't have 10 reputation :(. Please help

Here is the layout code and the parent layout is linear layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:background="#517398"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_agenda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/agenda_view" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/month_view" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/day_view" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image_agenda"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image_month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image_day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you Haresh, it works as I wanted. I think  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below Sample layout code i have made to test 
i dont know for what purpose you are using and how you are using the center element 2 textview so right now i have commented that if you want that center element all 2 textview and imagebutton with equal space distribution then same formula layout_weight you use that i have used for this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_agenda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <!--   <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="#000000" /> -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   <!--  <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" /> -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if you have any doubt you can ask me.....

Answer (score 0):

try Using Weight  Attribute and Avoid Using Relative Layout. Define WeightSum to parent Layout and weight to childs. It will work for both Tablet and Phones[portrait]

If u are trying to divide spaces acc. to width then give width = 0dp to childs and if Acc to height then give height 0dp to childs when using weights.

code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:background="#517398"
    android:weightSum="9" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_agenda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/agenda_view" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/month_view" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/day_view" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: Relative Layout do not support weight or WeightSum.